# Get orders between dates in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page created in Codeigniter that show my orders in day (today) and now i want to create an (this week).

To today, i have this code, and is working correctly:

```
$dataatual = date('Y-m-d');

if($status["today"] === true){
    $this->db->where('DATE(gp.data)', $dataatual);
}
```

I try this, but dont know how create to **this week** (monday starting)

```
$first_date  = date('Y-m-d'); //tried in manual date (2019-08-11)
$second_date = date('Y-m-d'); //tried in manual date (2019-08-17)

if($status["thisweek"] === true){
    $this->db->where('DATE(gp.data) >=', $first_date);
    $this->db->where('DATE(gp.data) <=', $second_date);
}
```

Comment: `DATE()` why are you using this,

Comment: To conver my datetime (2019-08-16 12:00:00) to YYYY-MM-DD, and in "today" orders its displaying correctly.

Comment: and what date do you need on tomorrow?

Comment: `$second_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+7 day", $first_date));` this will give you seven days + date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `DateTime` or `date` and `strtotime` methods to get the week starting and ending date like this:

```
$first_date  = (new DateTime('last sunday'))->format('Y-m-d'); // or date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last sunday'));
$second_date = (new DateTime('next saturday'))->format('Y-m-d'); // or date('Y-m-d', strtotime('next saturday'));

if($status["thisweek"] === true){
    $this->db->where('DATE(gp.data) >=', $first_date);
    $this->db->where('DATE(gp.data) <=', $second_date);
}
```